# Blazor Custom Bind - Get Property of model that changed

Tags: c#, blazor

I receive data from a SQL Server and load it into a model:

```
namespace BlazorServer.Models
{
    public class Animal
    {
        public int height { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string origin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In a component I use the model to display data. The user is able to edit the data. Here is a sample:

```
<input @onchange="args => ValueChanged(args)" value="@animal.name" class="form-control form-control-sm border rounded" />
```

How do I get which property of the model has changed? I tried the following, but I only get the new value:

```
private void ValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var newValue = args.Value;
}
```

I want to update the model in the component (which equals the binding of blazor) **AND** also send the data to the SQL server right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor comes with `EditForm` which manages an `EditContext`, and a set of Input controls - `InputText` in your case - that interface with `EditContext`.  You can access the `EditContext`, register an event handler on `OnFieldChanged` and get change events.  You get passed a `FieldIdentifier` that you can use to identify which field has been changed.

See - [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Here's a simple razor page that demos using `EditContext` and `OnFieldChanged`

```cs
@page "/Test"

@implements IDisposable

<EditForm EditContext="this.editContext" class="m-3">
    Animal: <InputText @bind-Value="this.model.name"></InputText><br />
    Origin: <InputText @bind-Value="this.model.origin"></InputText><br />
</EditForm>

<div class="m-3">FieldChanged:<i>@this.FieldChanged</i> </div>


@code {

    public class Animal
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string origin { get; set; }
    }

    private Animal model = new Animal() { height = 2, name = "giraffe", origin = "Africa" };

    private EditContext editContext;

    private string FieldChanged = "none";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(model);
        this.editContext.OnFieldChanged += this.OnFieldChanged;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.FieldIdentifier;
        this.FieldChanged = e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName;

    }

    // Need to  Implement IDisosable to unhook event handler
    public void Dispose ()
    {
        this.editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnFieldChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected. 
One issue left: How do I get the old/new value of the field that changed?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by old value.  The problem with the out-of-the-box controls is you only see the new value and last value.  With multiple edits you lose track of the original value  Personally I use a control I wrote called EditStateControl that  tracks changes from the original.  There's information here on my personal GitHub site - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/EditFormState.html.  Lift/duplicate the code if you want to use it.

Comment: The last value and the new value would fit my needs. My model has multiple properties (name, origin, height). How do I get the last and new value of the property that changed in the OnFieldChanged event?